# How to check if the disk is shared in Linux and AIX?

Tags: linux, aix

How to check if the disk is shared in Linux and AIX?

For example, let's say we have the `/dev/sdd` in `srv1` and `srv2` hosts and the disk must be shared across the two servers (the same disk). How can we make sure this is the same LUN?

Comment: I cannot help you, but I will point that you are not giving enough information. We have no idea if SAN, NAS, NFS or SAMBA is involved. Remember, don't drip feed information.

Comment: Yep. Shared – how? Please **edit** your question to include more detail about what you mean. If you happen to change your question after it gets closed due to lack of information, don't despair, we can always vote to reopen it, if the problems with the questions have been alleviated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux, if a disk has a `/dev/sd*` device, then it is not a remote NFS or Samba share, however it might be a local disk that is shared to other computer using these or other methods.

But if the potentially-shared disk appears as `/dev/sd*` in both hosts, then the disks could be local, or the sharing method could be anything from old differential-SCSI to iSCSI, ATAoE or FibreChannel. For all of these solutions, the disks will appear as local devices, yet might be shared with at least one other host. Differential-SCSI is limited to at most 2 hosts, while SAN solutions like iSCSI, ATAoE or FibreChannel could allow any number of hosts to share a disk.

In all these cases, a general method for checking the identity of a disk/LUN is checking the disk's serial number (or WWID, if it has one).

On modern Linux, you could use `lsblk -o +model,serial,wwn` to view the serial numbers and WWIDs of all disks at once. If the `lsblk` command is not available, then `lsscsi`, `sdparm --inquiry --page=di /dev/sdX` or `sdparm --inquiry --page=sn /dev/sdX` might be useful.

On AIX, `lscfg` with suitable options, e.g. `lscfg -vl hdiskN` should report the serial number and possibly WWID of the specified disk.

On virtualized environments like VMware, the virtualization platform may not always provide unique serial numbers or other IDs to virtual disks: in VMware, you will need to set the `disk.enableUUID=true` parameter in the VM configuration to have shared virtual disks be identifiable in this way. [See an example in this linked Dell Technologies guide](https://infohub.delltechnologies.com/l/best-practices-guide-deploying-oracle-12c-rac-database-on-dell-emc-xc-series-all-flash/how-to-identify-vmware-virtual-disks-in-linux-guest).

---

If the disk already contains something that includes a sufficiently unique identifier (like a filesystem UUID, LVM PV UUID, a PARTUUID or disk unique GUID of a GPT-partitioned disk, or the volume serial number on a MBR-partitioned disk), you could use those for identification too. However, since these are all based on information stored among the data, a cloned disk or a SAN-level snapshot of a disk would be indistinguishable from a shared original disk using these methods.

In Linux, `lsblk -o +UUID,PARTUUID,PTUUID` would be the easiest way to view all IDs of these types.

In AIX, `lspv` would show AIX LVM pvids, which could be used if the disk is already initialized for use with AIX LVM.

Comment: Having recently played with this, I can confirm that a `/dev/sd*` disk device in a Linux VM could certainly be shared behind the scenes through VMWare to another VM (multi-writer configuration). https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1034165 for a bit more background on that.

Comment: On the VMWare tangent, `lsblk -o +model,serial,wwn` did not reveal a serial number or a WWN; perhaps it's a local configuration difference, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: What does appear to give useful information on a VMWare disk is `lsblk -o +uuid`; the multi-writer disk has the same UUID, and non-shared disks have unique UUIDs, as expected.

Comment: On AIX, I *think* that the pvid would be synchronized between hosts as well, so an `lspv` or `lspv hdiskN` would uncover that as well.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Now I feel old; I did not think about virtualized constructs at all :-) `lsblk -o +uuid` will only give a result if a disk or partition has been initialized with a filesystem or a LVM PV; I cannot check right now but I believe AIX `lspv` would also only report on initialized PVs. So those only work if the disk has already been written to, or if you are free to overwrite existing contents, which may not always be the case. Just a minor nit, but I feel it needs to be mentioned to avoid the possibility of data-loss-causing mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! is exactly what I am looking for. In my tests only lsscsi, sdparm --inquiry --page=di /dev/sdX or sdparm --inquiry --page=sn /dev/sdX commands did not work. But I have find /usr/lib/udev/scsi_id --whitelisted --replace-whitespace --device=/dev/sdd where return the serial. Linux lsblk and aix lscfg command worked for me as well.